# How to define transition correctly in angular 5 animation?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I was able to run animation in the application but I'm trying with no success to
animate slide out, I've tried the following:

```
animations: [
        trigger('slideOut', [
            transition ('* => void', [
            animate('1000ms ease-out',
              style({ transform: 'translateY(200%)' })
            )
        ])
```

Nothing is moving. I need actually the height to be zero but this example
is just not moving as well.
This should be animate an info message from display to disappearing.
Thanks.

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `* => void` you are actually telling Angular to animate your component when it goes out of view. Do you remove your component from the view? You may try to *ngIf your component and when it goes out of view animation will trigger.

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-buqg7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) showing how to use this animation.